# How to include a directory to java.library.path on Linux/Debian?

Tags: java, linux, debian

I would like to add `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib` to `java.library.path` so it shows when running `java -XshowSettings:properties` - how can this be done?

I am running Linux/Debian

Comment: Have you tried this `java -XshowSettings:properties -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib` ?

Comment: That would replace the value of the property, most of the time you want to append to this property IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via adding the containing directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH like
**

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Desktop/pathOfContaininglibaryDirectory

**
 into your bashrc file.Then you need to refresh bashrc file via command

> **source ~/.bashrc**

then run you can run the java command(**java -XshowSettings:properties**) to see all the properties it will come under  **user.dir**

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that

if you want to set up a system environment in `/etc/profile` and validate it immediately (without reboot),

refresh profile via command `. /etc/profile`
( DOT SPACE `/etc/profile` )